# How to document which Context Provider is being used when calling useContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-context, jsdoc

I made a component that renders `AuthContext.Provider` with certain `value`s.

[image]

It works, but when I call `useContext` in a child of the `AuthProvider` component, VS Code can't tell the return type of `useContext`. Is there a way (i.e. with jsdoc comments) for me to document which Provider is being used so VS Code will show the correct type for `x`?

**What I see:**

[image]

**What I want to see:**

```
const x: {
    login: (username: any, password: any) => Promise<void>;
    logout: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

**NOTE:** I'd rather not hard-code all the `value` types in a jsdoc comment if they could be deduced from the Provider. Also, I'm not using Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type your `AuthContext` as a `Context<Type>` object:

```js
/**
 * Whatever your context object type.
 * @typedef ICTXDefault
 */

/**
 * @type {ICTXDefault}
 */
const defaultContext = {};

/**
 * @type {import("react").Context<ICTXDefault>}
 * 
const AuthContext = createContext(defaultContext);
```

Comment: It's still not detecting the types of the properties returned by useContext

Comment: Did you declare them with `@typedef`?

Comment: Inside `AuthProvider`, yeah

Comment: nevermind, I'll just hardcode the types. I was just trying to get VS code to associate the `value` types with the `useContext(AuthContext)` without having to hardcode the types

Comment: `Provider` is not directly related to the context passed to it (as far as types concerned). You have to extract it as a `@typedef` and reuse in both `createContext()` and `AuthProvider`.

Comment: Is it possible to define the `value` type with `@typedef` *inside* of `AuthProvider`, and then use that same type *outside* of `AuthProvider`?

Comment: No, type declarations follow the usual scoping rules. The other way is to use typescript util types such as  `ReturnType<FuncType>`/`Parameters<FuncType>`/`Pick<ObjType, Keys>`/`Omit<ObjType, Keys>` coupled with `typeof` operator (which works differently when used in types) to derive types from concrete values. But at that point you are using typescript already.